# Add Text on the Sectors of jQuery PieChart (HighCharts)

Tags: jquery, highcharts

As per my requirement I need to add the percentage(Size of the Sector) on the Sector of my jQuery Pie Chart (HighCharts) like below

[image]

But My Pie Chart is like this without any text on its sectors

[image]

I have tried many attributes in my .js file for displaying the text on the sectors of my pie chart , but no luck.

Here is my .js file

```
$(function () {
var chart;

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Build the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

});

This chart is being rendered to the div shown

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Can some one suggest me a piece of code which I can add to my .js file , so that it will display text on its sectors.

Comment: I'm afraid that it's not possible, because a sector can be very small to accommodate the text.

Comment: @MaheshSapkal, But In the first Chart shown above , it is there rite, but I didnt get the source of that chart.

Comment: I dont mean to say huge text, I want it to display a simple numeral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text should be added insie slices? If yes you can use datalabels with formatter http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter

EDIT:
You can use distance parameter with negative value http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.distance

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I want data labels to be displayed on the chart, the formatters which you suggested will display text out side the particular sector of pie chart with a line pointing to that text. But my requirement is that , I want the text to be displayed on the sector it self as i shown in the first diagram of this post, Could you please help out